# Nature and redundancy of classifiers

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

I am applying a set of linear and non-linear classification models in a classification task. The input data are language vectors (CountVectorizer, Word2Vec) and binary labels. In scikit-learn, I selected following estimators:

```
LogisticRegression(),
LinearSVC(),
XGBClassifier(),

SGDClassifier(),
SVC(), # Radial basis function kernel
BernoulliNB(), # Naive Bayes seems widely used for LV models
KNeighborsClassifier(),
RandomForestClassifier(),
MLPClassifier()
```

1. **Question:** Am I correct that `LinearSVC()` is a *linear*
   classifier, at least for the case of a binary estimator?
2. **Question:** In view of experts, is there any significant redundancy among the classifiers?

Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LogisticRegression()`, `LinearSVC()`, `SGDClassifier()` and `BernoulliNB()` are linear models.
With the default loss function `SGDClassifier()` works as a linear SVM, with log loss as a logistic regression, so one of these three is redundant. Also you could substitute `LogisticRegression()` for `LogisticRegressionCV()` which has built-in optimization for regularization hyperparameter.

`XGBClassifier()` and all the others are non-linear.

The list seems to include all the major `sklearn` classifiers.